# Connect to MSSQL v18 from Spring boot application using windows authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am currently using the below properties to connect to localhost from Java spring boot application:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=vlad;integratedSecurity=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
```

From Java spring boot this is not working. The error I get is:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
```

Comment: That's a generic error that could be caused by anything. There should be a more specific error describing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to configure your Dialect and Include a driver:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2016Dialect
```

You will also most likely need to add driver and auth dependency to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc_auth</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.1.x86</version>
        <type>dll</type>
    </dependency>
```

If that doesn't do the trick, you might have to manually download the Driver:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Hope it helps